# Можно ли использовать docker для Развертывания unix системы?

Tags: linux, windows, docker

У меня есть установленный Docker на Windows 10. Можно ли в него развернуть  Ubuntu и работать с ее термминалом? Устанавливать программы и т.д?

Comment: Ubuntu - можно, unix - нет

Comment: Да, но лучше использовать докер как докер. Хочешь "настоящего" линукса - поставь virtualbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не совсем ответ на ваш вопрос, скорее рекомендация.

В Windows есть родной гипервизор, для которого адаптированы несколько дистрибутивов Windows. Это называется [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), поставляется вместе с последними версиями Windows.

WSL 1 немного ограничена в функциональности, в частности, в ней не работает docker внутри гостя, зато файловая система Windows и сетевые порты доступны напрямую. WSL 2 - это настоящая виртуальная машина, в ней Linux работает как родной во всём великолепии, но localhost этой машины недоступен извне, что временами шибко неудобно - например при работе с Jupyter Notebook из браузера.

Я уже несколько лет пользуюсь [WSL+Ubuntu](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ubuntu/9PDXGNCFSCZV) и в целом очень доволен. Более того, в VS Code есть специальный тип Remote для разработки в WSL - получается кодить в Linux, оставаясь при этом в Windows (что бы ни говорили апологеты Линуха, ИМХО окошковый интерфейс в MS Windows гораздо удобнее).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит Windows Terminal с вкладкой Ubuntu и Power Shell.